# Data type mismatch in criteria expression MS Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

When i run the query the below, i get the error `Data type mismatch'

```
SELECT o.name as Name,
Month(CDate(type.Value)) as ValueType
FROM (t_obj as o
       INNER JOIN t_prop as type 
         ON o.Obj_ID = type.Obj_ID)
WHERE type.Property LIKE 'Tech*' 
  AND Month(type.Value) = 5
```

However if i run the query as follows, it works just fine

```
SELECT o.name as Name,
Month(CDate(type.Value)) as ValueType
FROM (t_obj as o
       INNER JOIN t_prop as type 
         ON o.Obj_ID = type.Obj_ID)
WHERE type.Property LIKE 'Tech*'
```

Answer (score 2):

`AND Month(type.Value) = 5`

To

`AND Month(CDate(type.Value)) = 5`